# Visualizing relative frequency in R / ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, frequency-distribution

I tried to wrap my head around the problem of how to visualize a bunch of relative frequencies in a way that makes it easy to see how they fare compared to each other. The differences aren't gigantic in terms of distribution, which, of course, I also consider something worthy to be shown. I've managed to create a relatively simple point plot, however, I don't think it really looks good enough.

The code is straightforward (albeit unfinished as far as visual tweaks are concerned), I guess:

```
library(ggplot2)
copuladeletion <- read.table(text = "Type    Distribution    Family
                             NP  0.39344 Austronesian    
                             NP  0.30232 Mon-Khmer
                             NP  0.3125  Tai-Kadai
                             NP  0.29230 Sinitic
                             NP  0.26785 Other
                             AdjP    0.44262 Austronesian
                             AdjP    0.53488 Mon-Khmer
                             AdjP    0.625   Tai-Kadai
                             AdjP    0.55384 Sinitic
                             AdjP    0.58928 Other
                             AdvP    0.03278 Austronesian
                             AdvP    0.00000 Mon-Khmer
                             AdvP    0.00000 Tai-Kadai
                             AdvP    0.04615 Sinitic
                             AdvP    0.07142 Other
                             EX  0.01639 Austronesian
                             EX  0.02325 Mon-Khmer
                             EX  0.00000 Tai-Kadai
                             EX  0.03076 Sinitic
                             EX  0.01785 Other
                             Clause  0.08196 Austronesian
                             Clause  0.02325 Mon-Khmer
                             Clause  0.0625  Tai-Kadai
                             Clause  0.03076 Sinitic
                             Clause  0.05357 Other
                             Other   0.01639 Austronesian
                             Other   0.11627 Mon-Khmer
                             Other   0.00000 Tai-Kadai
                             Other   0.04615 Sinitic
                             Other   0.00000 Other", header = TRUE)
ggplot(copuladeletion) + geom_point(aes(Distribution, Type, colour=Family,size=1))
```

Which yields the following image:

[image]

So, my questions are:

Do you think this visualization works well enough?
Are there any preferable options over a simple point plot for these data?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You can put size outside of `aes` so it doesn't get mapped to the legend. Since you have some overlapping points, consider adding a small amount of jitter (`geom_jitter()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps just another take on your strip charts:

```
library(ggplot2)

copuladeletion <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)

gg <- ggplot(copuladeletion) 
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(Distribution, Type, colour=Family),
                      shape="|", size=10)
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 0.7, 0.1))
gg <- gg + scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
gg <- gg + scale_colour_brewer(name="", palette="Set1")
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Type, ncol=1, scales="free_y")
gg <- gg + guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=15, size=3)))
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title="Family Distribution by Type")
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(strip.background=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(strip.text=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(legend.key=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="bottom")
gg
```

[image]

To slightly compensate for the overlaps (as Roman has pointed out a cpl times) you can use a proper line vs a hack-y point:

```
gg <- ggplot(copuladeletion) 
gg <- gg + geom_segment(aes(x=Distribution, xend=Distribution,
                            y=0, yend=1, colour=Family), size=0.25)
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 0.7, 0.1))
gg <- gg + scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
gg <- gg + scale_colour_brewer(name="", palette="Set1")
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Type, ncol=1, scales="free_y", switch="y")
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title="Family Distribution by Type")
gg <- gg + guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=15, size=3)))
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_rect(color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15))
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(strip.background=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(strip.text.y=element_text(angle=180))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(legend.key=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="bottom")
gg
```

[image]

You can add an aesthetic to map `linetype` as well (and `hjust` the y labels as you like). These thin lines are kinda hard to read (so tweak `size` at-will as well), but I do think a strip chart works pretty well for this data. You may want to "zoom out" the `EX` strip in a separate plot *if* you need to (I have no idea what this data really is trying to say :-)

Comment: Why so many assignments? Is assigning even necessary? It just makes more typing and perhaps less readable. This visualization has the down-side over the points proposed by OP of inability to be jittered.

Comment: Super great opinion @RomanLuštriz :-) I believe/opine (and can prove speed-wise in the context of composition) this idiom makes it easier to edit ggplot2 plots and I make pretty good plots. I'm not sure jittering is necessary either. If precision is required, another plot with a zoomed-in view can be generated. If folks don't like the assigns, translate to one giant, error-prone, comma-separated `theme()` parameter list.

Comment: This looks awesome, thank you so much! Once I'm done being excited about how cool this is, I'll also try to understand the coding behind it better. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you are plotting relative frequencies within each family, so alternatively to your plot, we could visualize the proportion of `Type` within each `Family` using a 100% stacked histogram.

```
ggplot(copuladeletion, aes(x = Family, y = Distribution, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position= "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous("Proportion") +
  scale_x_discrete("", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion! I also really like this approach. I tried creating a histogram like yours yesterday but, for some reason, it never looked this nice. While I will probably use the other option given, I really appreciate your effort as it might help me in understanding where I made a wrong step in my coding yesterday!